# Why isn't the product topology on $X_i = \{0,1\}$ equipped with the discrete topology, discrete?

Tags: general-topology

In this example, we defined $X = \prod_{i\in1}^\infty X_i$ where for all $i$, $X_i = \{0,1\}$, and we endow $X_i$ with the discrete topology. The point of the example we did was to show the difference between the box topology and the product topology in this case; in particular we showed that the box topology on $X$ is the discrete topology on $X$, while the product topology is not. We define the basis of the product topology to be $\mathscr{B} = \{\prod_{i \in I} U_i\}: U_i \text{ is open in } X_i, \text{ and } U_i \neq X_i \text{ for only finitely many i}\}$.

Given an element $b \in X$, $b$ can be thought of as some sequence of bits, $\{b_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $b_i$ is just $0$ or $1$. We noted the basic open neighbourhoods of the product topology are given by $U = \prod_{i=1}^n \{b_i\} \times \prod_{i=n+1}\{0,1\}$. The part I am getting confused about is why $U$ does not generate all sequences $\{b_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$.

**EDIT: Due to the question being unclear; I summarise below** (I don't want to change the entire question as there are already answers). Take the example for $n=1$. So we consider basis elements of the form $\prod_{i=1}^1 \{b_i\} \times \prod_{i = 2}^\infty \{X_i\}$. Say for the first basis element, we choose $\{b_i\} = \{0\}$. This element restricts the bit sequence to $(0,...)$, with just the first coordinates restricted to $0$, all others unrestricted in $X_i = \{0,1\}$. Now consider a basis element where we choose $\{b_i\} = \{1\}$. Now the bit sequence looks like $(1,...)$. So in this case, the two basis elements look like they came from a product where the associated set for the first coordinate is $X_i$. This is precisely what I don't understand. I can't see why restricting $U_i \neq X_i$ to finitely many cases makes a difference. Since the topology is discrete, I can just take the singletons $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ as choices for two basis elements, but the two elements look like I chose the first coordinates from $\{0,1\}$. **Ultimately, I don't see what sequence of bits can exist in the box topology basis that cannot exist in the product topology basis.**

Comment: It seems a good question. Perhaps shortening the question would make it clearer?

Comment: The base you gave in the third paragraph is in fact the base in the product topology, *not* the box topology.

Comment: @CharlieChang Yes I realise my question is not well phrased; I might put an edit at the summarising rather than changing the whole question since there have already been some answers!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you, I will fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \{0,1\}$ would be discrete. Let $\{(x_n)_n\}$ be a singleton set in this product, and this would have to be open.

So there is a basic open subset $\prod_{i=1}^N \{x_i\} \times \prod_{i=N+1}^\infty \{0,1\}$ that is a subset of $\{(x_n)_n\}$, for some $N$.

But it's clear that this inclusion will never hold: pick any $y_{N+1} \in \{0,1\}$ different from $x_{N+1}$ then the point $(y_n)_n$, with $y_n = x_n$ for all $n \neq N+1$ and $y_{N+1}$ as picked, is in the basic subset (all choices are free above $N$!) but *not* in the singleton, we made it a distinct point from $(x_n)_n$. So no point of the product is isolated, so it's a strong contrast with the discrete topology!

With the product topology we can impose only *finitely many* demands on coordinates at the same time, the box topology can have conditions on *all* coordinates at the same time, so all singletons are basic open here as $\{(x_n)_n\}= \prod_{i=1}^\infty \{x_i\}$, but with basic open sets we have no "control" beyond a finite set of coordinates.

Comment: The part I'm not getting is why this control over the choice of the $\{s_i\}$ matters in this case. Since the topology on $\{0,1\}$ is discrete, all the singletons are open. Doesn't this mean that since $U_i$ can be any open set, I can choose either $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ for any particular coorindate? I hope that is clear, I am having a hard time explaining what I mean concisely. I tried to update the original question.

Comment: @masiewpao for a basic open set you only have finitely many such choices. That’s crucial.

Comment: Thank you, your answer and that comment helped make it click. I also realised I was thinking about the 'set structure' of the products wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you are doing here, but in the product topology, one needs
$U_i=\{0,1\}$ for almost all $i$, and so one cannot keep choosing either $U_i=\{0\}$
or $U_i=\{1\}$.

Anyway, here is an argument as who why the product topology is not discrete.
Let $z=(0,0,0,\ldots) $ be the zero sequence, and let $y_n=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$
be the sequence all-zero apart from a $1$ in position $n$. I claim that
$y_n\to z$ in the product topology. (That would be impossible in a discrete topology).

A neighbourhood of $z$ must contain a set of the form
$$N=\{0\}\times\{0\}\cdots\times\{0\}\times\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\cdots$$
where the first $k$ factors are $\{0\}$ and the remainder $\{0,1\}$. Then $y_n\in N$
for $n>k$, and so $y_n\to z$.

It is possible to describe completely when a sequence converges in the product
topology. Let $a\in X=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \{0,1\}$ and let $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$
be a sequence of points in $X$. Then $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ with the $a_k\in\{0,1\}$ and $b_n=(b_{n,1},b_{n,2},\ldots)$ with the $b_{n,k}\in\{0,1\}$.
Then $b_n\to a$ iff for each $k$ the sequence $(b_{1,k},b_{2,k},\ldots)$
converges to $a_k$, in the sense that $(b_{1,k},b_{2,k},\ldots)$
is eventually constant, and that constant is $a_k$.

Comment: I think the part I am not following is what you hit on in the first paragraph. I don't see why in this discrete instance choosing $U_i = \{0\} \text{ or } \{1\}$ is different from choosing $X_i$. Because if we choose $\{0\}$ for the first coordinate in some basis element, then $\{1\}$ for a different basis element, and we leave all coordinates after this unrestricted, isn't this the exact same space as taking $\{X_i\}$ to be the choice at every coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $Y := \{(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in X : |\{i \in \mathbb N : x_i = 1\}| < \aleph_0\}.$

If $X$ is discrete, then the closure of $Y$ in $X$ must be $Y$, but we claim that $Y$ is in fact dense in $X$. Indeed, for any positive integer $k$, and any $i_1,\dots,i_k \in \mathbb N$, in the open set $$\pi_{i_1}^{-1}(U_1) \cap \cdots \cap \pi_{i_k}^{-1}(U_k) \quad \textrm{where $U_j \subseteq \{0,1\}$ is non-empty for each $j$,}$$ we can find a point $(y_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ that intersects $Y$, namely, $(y_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ such that $y_i=0$ for $i \notin \{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$ and $y_{i_j} \in U_j$ for each $j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$. Hence, every non-empty (basic) open set in $X$ intersects $Y$, and then $Y$ is dense in $X$.

---

*Note*. $\pi_\alpha : X \to X_\alpha$ is the function that takes $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ to $x_\alpha$.